# Problem installing tensorflow in virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

This issue in some form has come up before, however I am having a variant of this issue.

I had **python 3.8** installed. Tensorflow does not have a version for this python.

I therefore **installed python 3.7** and set up a virtual environment using **virtualenv**.

In visual studio code I even updated the settings json "python.pythonPath": to the correct path for version 3.7 of python.

I install the correct version of tensorflow using the correct link for 3.7 on the site:

'''pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl'''

But i still get the error

> "ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

When i type python -V I still get Python 3.8.1, could this mean I am not correctly using the virtual environment?

However I have now set up virtual environment using anaconda which is limited to 3.7 and it still says 3.8 when using "python -V" and i get the same error when trying to install.

Comment: Try with Python 3.6. I had kind of same issue while using conda environment with 3.8, but once I use Python 3.6, it was resolved.

Comment: _However I have now set up virtual environment using anaconda which is limited to 3.7_ Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Aah I think I may have found the issue. I’m guessing you’re on windows, right? Why are you explicitly downloading the package from that link, by the way?

Comment: Thanks it resolved with Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You can try to either reinstall anaconda, visual studio, or type in the command "pip install --upgrade tensorflow". This should work without the link.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the virtual environment you need to activate it if you haven't already. Once you do, your command line prompt should indicate that a new version of Python, in your case 3.7 is now running.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Anaconda with Python 3.6, it seems tensorflow would not work for 3.7 on windows.